# Redefinir variável

Tags: c++, variáveis

Existe algum modo de redefinir a variável sem atribuir todos os valores novamente?
ex:

```
int number = 5 + rand() % 5 + 1;
cout << number << endl;
cout << number << endl;
```

Se a randomização for igual a 3, nos dois cout's retornariam 8. Gostaria de algo como:
redefine(number);

Ficando assim:

```
int number = 5 + rand() % 5 + 1;
cout << number << endl;
redefine(number);
cout << number << endl;
```

Assim retornaria 8 e outro numbero.
ps: Sem ter que escrever toda a definição da variável novamente.

Comment: Não sei se entendi o que quer. Você quer que a expressão que foi atribuída para `number` execute novamente? Você já viu isto em alguma outra linguagem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se eu entendi o que deseja, exatamente desta forma não é possível e desconheço uma forma de fazer isto em qualquer linguagem.

É possível fazer algo diferente que produz o resultado desejado usando uma função.

```
int gerador() {
    return 5 + rand() % 5 + 1;
}

int main() {
    int number = gerador();
    cout << number << endl;
    number = gerador();
    cout << number << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ML90Ij). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/oniurqoz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/Redefine.cpp).

Existe uma sintaxe mais simplificada chamada [*lambda*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) no C++11 mas ela não existe exatamente para este tipo de utilização. Seria algo assim:

```
int main() {
    auto gerador = []() { return 5 + rand() % 5 + 1; };
    int number = gerador();
    cout << number << endl;
    number = gerador();
    cout << number << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/HvbPcC). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jeubnlam-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/Lambda.cpp).

Não sei se notou, como você não inicializou a geração dos randômicos com algum número pego ao caso, sempre gera a mesma sequência de números em cada execução já que esta geração é pseudo-aleatória. Para inicializar é comum fazer [`srand(time(0));`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand)

Comment: Queria saber se existia algum modo. Entendi. Quanto ao srand, ja estou ciente. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Variáveis servem para **guardar** informação. Talvez o que você precise é de uma **função**?

```
int get_number() {
    return 5 + rand() % 5 + 1;
}

int main() {
    cout << get_number() << endl;
    cout << get_number() << endl;
}
```